# How to require .NET 3.5 framework?

Tags: .net-3.5

My client-side app is built using .NET 3.5, in fact, I want to require that the user has it installed.  Before I even start the app, I want to make sure that the framework is present on the box.

I tried to use the

`<requiredRuntime version="v3.5..."/>`

but it seems that the underlying code can't really tell between .net 2 and .net 3.5 (which, i know, it's the same thing).

So how do I check for presence of the .NET 3.5 framework, preferably in a declarative manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deploying your application through an MSI generated with a Setup and Deployment project you could enforce a [.NET Framework Launch Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxyh2e6a(v=VS.80).aspx). If it is a simple copy of the executable you could probably probe for the presence of `System.Core` assembly with reflection as this assembly is specific to .NET 3.5 but if the user has no CLR 2.0 installed this will fail.

Comment: I know there's a similar plugin to the NSIS installer framework too that lets you check for .Net framework version and auto-install the .Net framework if it doesn't exist.